# Build empty SASS file

Tags: css, sass

After having create a Sass file, I would like to create a copy of this file with only the structure (only the class and the id, but not the css properties).

Is it possible ? And how ?
Google doesn't help me ...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Copy it and delete the class properties, or do you mean do it automatically? I doubt it...

Comment: I would like to do it automatically. With Gulp or Grunt for example.

Comment: The reason why you can't find it is because it is not a feature of Sass.  You're essentially asking for a tool to do this, and tool requests are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your selectors, you can put CSS comment inside your differents blocks.
They will be present in your compiled stylesheet.

```
this-selector {
  // will not be present
}

but-this-one {
  /* will */
}
```

For an automatic parsing, you should try with [postcss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) and, for exemple, a node.js script.